# How to set values for Solidity contract state variables from JavaScript front-end?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, dapp-development

I am trying to set values to the following contract public state variables from a frontend javascript code. But it seems not working.

Contract public state variables:

```
// Current state of the auction.
address public highestBidder;
uint public highestBid;
```

In the below Javascript code, I get the values for address and amount from UI and assign to highestBidder & highestBid. But it seems not working. How do I do this?

```
// Submit bid details, triggered by the "Bid" button
SimpleAuction.prototype.startAuction = function() {
    console.log("inside startAuction");
    var that = this;
    console.log("inside startAuction");
    // Gets form input values
    var address = $("#enter-address").val();
    var amount = $("#enter-amount").val();
    console.log(amount);

    // Validates address using utility function
    if (!isValidAddress(address)) {
        console.log("Invalid address");
        return;
    }
    that.highestBidder = address;
    
     
    // Validate amount using utility function
    if (!isValidAmount(amount)) {
        console.log("Invalid amount");
        return;
    }
    that.highestBid = amount;
```

**This code fixed the issue**. Passing address and amount as a transaction object in the bid() function in JS

```
// Submit bid details, triggered by the "Bid" button
SimpleAuction.prototype.startAuction = function() {
    console.log("inside startAuction");
    var that = this;
    console.log("inside startAuction");
    // Gets form input values
    var address = $("#enter-address").val();
    var amount = $("#enter-amount").val();
    console.log(amount);

    // Validates address using utility function
    if (!isValidAddress(address)) {
        console.log("Invalid address");
        return;
    }
     
    // Validate amount using utility function
    if (!isValidAmount(amount)) {
        console.log("Invalid amount");
        return;
    }
    
    
    // Calls the public `bid` function from the smart contract
    this.instance.bid(
         {  
            from: address,
            value: amount,
            gas: 100000,
            gasPrice: 100000,
            gasLimit: 100000
        },
       
        function(error, txHash) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            // If success, wait for confirmation of transaction,
            // then clear form values
            else {
                that.waitForReceipt(txHash, function(receipt) {
                    if (receipt.status) {
                        $("#enter-address").val("");
                        $("#enter-amount").val("");
                    } else {
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to update the state of the contract and in this case it is required that you have to sign transaction. Take a look at web3 `sendTransaction` method over [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction). When you take a look at the method you will notice parameter `transactionObject` include `data` string which is the function ABI of your smart contract method. You can get function abi by using [encodeABI](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=encodeABI#methods-mymethod-encodeabi).

Then at your smart contract just by creating a variable the following way `address public highestBidder;` does not mean that this state variable can be updated. You have to create a setter method or include the setter method logic into another method, example:

```
function setHighestBidder(address _highestBidder) {
    highestBidder = _highestBidder;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! What I am trying to do is develop a UI for the Simple Auction contract in Solidity docs - https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.11/solidity-by-example.html. The contract works fine when I run from remix. The bid() function is payable but does not accept arguments. I am not sure how to pass the bid amount value to the contract from my UI. That's where I am stuck.

Comment: Ok, show us your front end connection to the smart contract so we can see where you are stuck at the moment.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by passing the transaction object with address and amount in the JS function bid(). Updated the code fixed above. I am still little confused because the smart contract function bid() does not accept arguments and how can I pass a transaction object in the corresponding JS function?